# ControlTemplate DataTrigger is not working, but a normal Trigger does. Why?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a `Button` which uses a `ControlTemplate`, this template contains multiple `MultiDataTriggers` which change the appearance depending on User Interaction and View Model properties. Therefore, I cannot use traditional `Triggers`.

The Triggers in question (examples)

**XAML:**

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsPressed, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Value="True">
    <Setter TargetName="Text" Property="Content" Value="IsPressed"/>
</DataTrigger>

<Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
    <Setter TargetName="Text" Property="Content" Value="IsPressed"/>
</Trigger>
```

The DataTrigger fails, yet the normal Trigger does not. Why?

**Note:**

I have tried multiple approaches to binding, such as `AncestorType`, but have had no success. These triggers have also been tested independently with the same problem persisting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `{RelativeSource Self}`:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsPressed, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True">
    <Setter TargetName="Text" Property="Content" Value="IsPressed"/>
</DataTrigger>
```

Comment: Incredible, it works. I don't know what's worse. That I didn't think to try it, or that the property cannot be resolved in the DataContext.